# How to convert Task<JArray> to JArray

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to call an async method from a console application. The method returns Task to the Main method. When I try to query the FirstOrDefault, I am getting, "Task doesn't contain a definition for FirstOrDefault". I tried to cast the result to (JArray), but it says, "Can not convert type System.Tasks.Task to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

```
static async  void  Main(){
     var result = Task.Run(() => MakeClientRequest());
     string employeeId = result
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<string>("employeeSequence") == "284")?
      .Value<string>("id");
}

static async Task<JArray> MakeClientRequest()
{
....
....
JArray data = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You either have to `await` a task to get the actual value asynchronously or synchronously wait by calling `Result`.  Either way I don't see why you'd need `Task.Run` here.

Comment: Let alone the fact that an `async void Main` will exit the application much earlier than what you would expect

Comment: Hi Camilo, I saw the Main method running twice! Not sure why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply `await` the result:

```
static async void Main()
{
     var result = await MakeClientRequest();
     string employeeId = result
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<string>("employeeSequence") == "284")?
      .Value<string>("id");
}
```

There isn't any good reason to kick off a `Task` here to get the result, at least not that I can see in the code that the OP posted.

If you **really** don't want to use `await` here for some reason, you could wait for the task to complete:

```
var result = MakeClientRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But really this is the same thing the compiler generates when you write `var result = await ...`.

Comment: Earlier I was using the GetResult(), but was told that it will cause a deadlock!

Comment: @Massey It is possible for it to deadlock when using it in an ASP.NET or UI application, but you are calling it from a console application and you don't have those issues. [Stephen Cleary wrote about it](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and it is a good read.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks!